# Ajuda em Procv para selecionar dados

Tags: microsoft-excel, procv

Tenho uma base de dados em que um funcionário tem três dependentes ou mais, quando faço um `PROCV` para puxar um dependente de cada vez, só aparece o primeiro e o último.

```
=PROCV(B35;'SÓCIOS COOP'!C:G;5;1)
```

Como faço para selecionar o primeiro em uma coluna o segundo em outra coluna e assim por diante?

EXEMPLO

Tenho na base dados estes valores:

```
216 WILLIAN         Filho   BRUNO 

216 WILLIAN         Filho   LUIS 

216 WILLIAN         Filho   YASMIN
```

Fiz um PROCV em outra planilha para deixar um pai e em outras colunas os filhos, consegui puxar através do PROCV o primeiro filho e ao ultimo. Mas não consigo puxar o filho do meio.

```
216 WILLIAN         Filho    BRUNO  Filho   YASMIN
```

Comment: Sugiro dar um exemplo dos valores que tem e do que pretende obter. O `PROCV` apenas trás um valor, e é o referente à coluna que é o terceiro parametro, no seu exemplo o `5`. Se precisa de três valores faça 3 `PROCV` trocando o parâmetro de coluna.

Comment: Amigo, o procv traz sempre a primeira ocorrência que encontra na coluna indicada.... então para fazer o que precisa vai ter de usar algo a mais do que um procv. Algo do tipo, ordenar a tabela de dependente por nome do funcionário, contar quantas ocorrências tem, buscar o primeiro e mais o número de ocorrências encontradas... as fórmulas indice e corresp podem te ajudar nisso ai. Dê uma olhada aqui: http://excelguru.com.br/excel-2/indice-corresp/ - sugiro editar sua pergunta de forma completa... mais tarde poderei publicar uma sugestão de resposta. boa sorte!