# Ajuda em Procv Copiar dados

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, excel-vba, procv

Tenho uma base de dados em que um funcionário tem três dependentes ou mais, quando faço um PROCV para puxar um dependente de cada vez, só aparece o primeiro e o último.

Como faço para selecionar o primeiro em uma coluna o segundo em outra coluna e assim por diante?

EXEMPLO

Tenho na base dados estes valores:

216 WILLIAN         Filho   BRUNO

216 WILLIAN         Filho   LUIS

216 WILLIAN         Filho   YASMIN

Fiz um PROCV em outra planilha para deixar um pai e em outras colunas os filhos, consegui puxar através do PROCV o primeiro filho e ao ultimo. Mas não consigo puxar o filho do meio.

216 WILLIAN         Filho    BRUNO  Filho   YASMIN

Também fiz um codigo que acredito estar correto na logica, porem não consigo fazer com que ele copie os dados de uma pasta para outra...

```html
Sub limpar()

Dim num As Integer
Dim contChave, contPrincipal As Integer
Dim numDependente As Integer
Dim idAtual As Integer

contPrincipal = 2
contChave = 2
Sheets("Chave").Select
Cells(contChave, 2).Select
Do While ActiveCell.Value <> ""
    num = ActiveCell.Value
    numDependente = 0
    Sheets("SÓCIOS COOP").Select
    idAtual = Cells(contPrincipal, 3).Value
    
    Do While num = idAtual
        numDependente = numDependente + 1
        Set depAtual = Range(Cells(contPrincipal, 6), Cells(contPrincipal, 8))
        Sheets("Chave").Select
        Set depend = Range(Cells(contChave, (1 + numDependentes * 3)), Cells(contChave, (1 + numDependentes * 3 + 2)))
    
        depAtual.Copy depend
        contPrincipal = contPrincipal + 1
        Sheets("SÓCIOS COOP").Select
        Cells(contPrincipal, 3).Select
        idAtual = ActiveCell.Value
        
    Loop
    contChave = contChave + 1
    Sheets("Chave").Select
    Cells(contChave, 2).Select
    
Loop








End Sub
```

Comment: É duplicata desta mas o site não permite a sinalização:[Ajuda em Procv para selecionar dados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/225917/ajuda-em-procv-para-selecionar-dados)

Comment: ok desisto.....

Comment: Não é sua essa pergunta do link?

Comment: Sim, mas não esta errado?

Comment: Não, se você já fez a pergunta, não precisava duplicar. Vi que criou outra conta e por isso não conseguirá editar a outra. Sugiro que crie uma conta fixa e solicite merge(uniao) das contas através desse link: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/contact

Answer (score 0):

Bom vamos lá, acho que você precisa definir uma variável para salvar, tente isso:

```
Set depend = Range(Cells(contChave, (1 + numDependentes * 3)), Cells(contChave, (1 + numDependentes * 3 + 2))).Copy
```